# How to Connect Secure Shell App to a Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-chrome-os

I would like to connect to a Google Cloud VM instance using Secure Shell App (SSA). I assumed this would be easy as these are both Google products and I had no problem before connection SSA to a Digital Ocean Droplet.  I have found Google's own documentation to do so [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) and it looked easy enough to follow.  However, the following link in the instructions: [Providing public SSH keys to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#provide-key) leads down a rabbit hole of confusing and seemingly self-contradicting information. I tried to follow it the best I could but kept running into errors. I have searched in vain for better instructions and am still astounded that Google has made it so hard to connect their own products. Is it really this hard to make this work?  Are there any better instructions out there?  If not, would someone be willing to write up clear and simple instructions?

Comment: I think it would help to understand exactly what steps you have performed and what errors or issues you encountered.  Without knowing what you did and where the problem was encountered, we don't have much to add.

Comment: As the instructions appear non-linear and have gaps and contradictions, I have tried multiple things to no avail.  I guess maybe I should have started at the end. It says "In the Identity field, select the private SSH key file that you want to use to connect to the instance".  How do I get get that private SSH ket to select?

Comment: In Cloud Shell use the command `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME`. You will then find the private key in the directory `.ssh` located in your home directory. The private key file is `google_compute_engine`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh

Comment: Tried the above. Got the following error: gcloud compute ssh coder
Did you mean zone [us-west1-b] for instance: [coder] (Y/n)?  Y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
 - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Comment: I created a brand new default Compute Engine called "xyz".  When started, I then opened a Cloud Shell and ran `gcloud compute ssh xyz`.  This logged me in.  I am understanding that you are not seeing same?

Comment: I am able to log into Google Clod Shell automatically.  My issue is with trying to log into the Secure Shell App

Comment: So before when I tried to go into the ssh directory I got permission denied.  That was in a ssh directory with a name I think was created when I was following the Google instructions.  There was another folder with my gmail address as its name that has an ssh folder i could access.  I use cat to get the private key and saved it as google_comput_engine.txt.  I then selected it in the Identity Field and tired again.  Still got the error: Permission denied (publickey).
NaCl plugin exited with status code 255.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this step by step instruction:

1. create a new VM `instance-1`
2. connect to it with `gcloud compute ssh instance-1` (*as mentioned @John Hanley*)
3. check `~/.ssh` folder

   ```
   $ ls -l ~/.ssh
   -rw------- 1 user usergroup 1856 Dec  9 17:12 google_compute_engine
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user usergroup  417 Dec  9 17:12 google_compute_engine.pub
   ```
4. copy keys

   ```
   cp ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub mykey.pub
   cp ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine mykey
   ```
5. follow [instructions](https://nagarajtantri.blogspot.com/2016/09/connect-to-remote-shell-using-chrome.html) from step 7 - create connection and import identity
6. (*optional*) if you don't find your `mykey` in the `Indentity` list try to connect anyway (ended with an error as expected), then restart Secure Shell App and check `Indentity` menu again (they should be there without redoing import again)

After that, I successfully  connected to my VM via [Secure Shell App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/related?hl=en).

Comment: From your solution, it looks like my issue might be not including the public key in the Identity.  However, when I tried to upload the public key into Identity, the file never appears, no matter how many times I reload SSA.  I tried changing the extension to pb instead of pub and this worked for getting it into the Identity, but then I got the same error as before when I tried to connect.  Are you able to make .pub files appear in the Identity?

Comment: I selected both files as it was described in the instruction and then, after restart, I was able to select them as Identity. In Identity they were named like `mykey` without separating.

Comment: So after selecting mykey and mykey.pub, just mykey appeared in the Identity field and you selected that, correct?  If so, I have done that and it is still refusing to connect.

Comment: Did you follow the instruction and fill all the information as ut was described? Did you try to connect using external IP instead of name of your instance?

Comment: I did not start over with a new instance as I was opening to make my current one work.  However, I will now try that to see if it works.  One question, why does one need to make duplicates of the public and private keys? Can't one just use the original google_compute_engine key?

Comment: Ok followed from beginning and got: 
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:hKV3RkIT8tg/uksT3mVF41x/jB4YDowC668tkk9HedY.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
ECDSA host key for 34.83.134.204 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: Did you do anything with keys at VM? Try to remove host key for your VM from `/.ssh/known_hosts` and then try to connect again. It'll be easier if you update your question with provided steps including commands, outputs and some screenshots.